# Uploading A file in django with ModelForms

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have been hacking away at this project for many hours now and just cannot figure out how to create a simple file upload app. I have looked at all the tutorials but none quite apply to my situation and i just cant get the code right. I know the code I have at this point wont run but I was hoping somone might be able to push me in the right direction with what I have. I know its not great but Im getting frustrated and I hope someone could help especially with my views.py  Thank you so much. Thank you in advance!

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm


class WorkSheet(models.Model):
    worksheet_name = models.CharField(max_length= 150, default = True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, default = True)
    worksheet_file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'worksheets', default = True)
    number_of_stars = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = 0)


class UploadWorkSheetForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkSheet
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from django import http


from models import WorkSheet
from forms import UploadWorkSheetForm

def upload(request):
    template = 'upload.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' in request.FILES:
            file = request.FILES['file']
            filename = file['filename']
            fd = open('%s/%s' % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename), 'wb')
            fd.write(file['content'])
            fd.close()

            return http.HttpResponseRedirect('upload_success.html')
    else:
        form = UploadWorkSheetForm()
        return render_to_response(template, {'form': form})

    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

**Upload.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WSD Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload WorkSheet</h1>
{% block body %}
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {{ form }}
    <type="submit" value = "Upload"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

If there is anything else you need please tell me. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Is there an error or does it just not do what you want it to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

views.py

```
def upload(request):
    template = 'upload.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadWorkSheetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('upload_success.html') <---change this to your valid url not template name
    else:
        form = UploadWorkSheetForm()

    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

template

```
...................        
{% block body %}
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    {% csrf_token %}    
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value = "Upload"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
....................
```

Comment: if you have other question just tell me

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed! Just one more question though, I dont see a button where i can "submit" this even though there is definitley a form.save()   is it just not showing up in my broswer or does the html/template  not put a button there? Thanks again

Comment: This is the button `<input type="submit" value = "Upload"/>`, don't you recognize the code?

Comment: That is what I thought! But for some reason it does not show up? I will recheck my code

Comment: Yep I just forgot the "input" at the beginning. Sorry for the stupid questions you really helped me out!

Comment: ah ok I see it in your original code you forgot the `<input>`

Comment: But.... Now when I click upload it tells me 'UploadWorkSheetForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: I think you override the save method somewhere in your file. You must remove that.

Comment: Ok I know this is too many questions already and I am really sorry to keep asking you all these questions but what file exactly? The one I am uploading?

Comment: No, I mean models.py, or in your forms.py. Remember where you override the save method

Comment: It turns out I needed to use ModelForms instead or atleast that worked. Thank you for all of your help!