# Django file upload with model form

Tags: django, file-upload

there are tons of relevant posts:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/
- [Uploading A file in django with ModelForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846120/uploading-a-file-in-django-with-modelforms)
- https://github.com/axelpale/minimal-django-file-upload-example

I am creating a simple app that allow user to upload css file:

> First, validate field field to make sure the file is **css** and the max size does not exceed 5MB.

`fields.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.template.defaultfilters import filesizeformat


def mb(n):
    return n * 1048576


class FileField(models.FileField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.content_types = kwargs.pop('content_types', [])
        self.max_upload_size = kwargs.pop('max_upload_size', [])
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super().clean(*args, **kwargs)
        file = data.file

        try:
            content_type = file.content_type
            if content_type in self.content_types:
                if file.size > self.max_upload_size:
                    raise forms.ValidationError('Please keep filesize under {}. Current filesize {}'
                    .format(filesizeformat(self.max_upload_size), filesizeformat(file.size)))
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('File type rejected')
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return data
```

> second, implement validation into model

`models.py`

```py
# Create your models here.
class Css(models.Model):
    file = FileField(
        upload_to='css', 
        content_types=['text/css'],
        max_upload_size=mb(5),
    )
```

> third, create form for model creation

`forms.py`

```py
class CssCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Css
        fields = ['file']
```

> last, write a callable view

`views.py`

```py
# Create your views here.
def cssUploadView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST['file'])
        print(type(request.POST['file']))
        print(request.FILES)
        form = forms.CssCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('---------')
            print(form.cleaned_data['file'])
        else:
            print('not valid')
    else:
        form = forms.CssCreateForm()
        return render(request, 'css/css_create.html', {
            'form': form,
        })
```

`template`

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-title">Upload a new CSS file</div>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="button-area">
        <button id="go" type="submit">Go</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

The expected result is that

- when uploading html file, or css file larger than 5MB, `ValidationError` will be raised

However, in view

- Both `request.FILES` and `form.cleaned_data['file']` fails to retrieve uploaded file.
- `form.is_valid` always returns `True`

> for example, when I upload `clean.py`:

```
clean.py
<class 'str'>
<MultiValueDict: {}>
---------
None
```

---

I wonder why file fails to upload and validation does not work. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your template please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the data encoding method in your html form.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-title">Upload a new CSS file</div>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="button-area">
        <button id="go" type="submit">Go</button>
    </div>
</form>
```